# Unresolved import `sp_core::to_substrate_wasm_fn_return_value`

Tags: build, cargo

When building the runtime useing `cargo build --release` I'm running into this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `sp_core::to_substrate_wasm_fn_return_value`
    --> /home/christian/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/api/src/lib.rs:80:9
     |
  80 | pub use sp_core::to_substrate_wasm_fn_return_value;
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `to_substrate_wasm_fn_return_value` in the root

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
  error: could not compile `sp-api` due to previous error
```

I tried `cargo update` and `rustup update`

I looked at the `.../primitives/core/src/lib.rs` file and it does have `pub fn to_substrate_wasm_fn_return_value` implemented, so I don't know why it can't find it.

I'm new to rust so I don't fully know how to troubleshoot this. Any Ideas?

Comment: An unconstrained `cargo update` is usually not a good idea. `cargo update -p sp-io` is usually ok though.

Comment: if you do a cargo build --release from the root that would build the pallets in wasm too. I would undo local changes and make sure that you have run `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`

Comment: @bkchr, that helped but not directly. I broke out a separate crate for some shared logic between two pallets, and I had to add `default-features = false` and then add that crate to `std`.